# Is there a metric on a finite-dimensional (non-trivial) vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$ which makes it compact?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that a finite-dimensional (non-trivial) vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$ which is *normed* isn't compact, but what about when it has a metric in general?

Comment: Not if you want that the vector space map $\mathbb{R}\times V\to V$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any bijection $f: V  \to [0,1] $ and define $d(v,w)=|f(v)-f(w)|$.  This makes $V$ compact.